# Using ADO.NET in the IDE integrated in Excel

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, ado.net

I want to build an *authentication system* based on an Excel spreadsheet database. Therefore I would like to know if it's possible to use `ADO.NET` in the IDE integrated in Excel. (I don't want to use visual basic studio)

Comment: ": I would like to know if it's possible to use ADO.NET in the IDE integrated in microsoft Excel - Yes. But your real problem is here -->> "I want to build an authentification system based on an Excel spreadsheet database"

Comment: Actually I managed to build an authentification system based on an Excel spreadsheet database in visual basic studio and I want to do the same in the IDE of microsoft Excel. I tried to use the method described here : [link](http://www.beansoftware.com/NET-Tutorials/Excel-ADO.NET-Database.aspx) but I don't know how to apply it to the file structure of the IDE of microsoft Excel

Comment: I wasn't questioning whether it was possible or not. I'm saying that it might not be an appropriate choice.

Comment: Ok, can you give more arguments about that ?

Comment: Not without information about the actual problem you are trying solve

Comment: You should use `ADODB` com objects for using `Microsoft ActiveX Data Object`  ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a reference to the ActiveX Data Objects, you can use the ADODB suite of objects - Connection, Command, ResultSet etc.

I presume what you'd do is just show the "Login" sheet on opening the file and then, on successful authentication, show other sheets.

As it's Excel though, I'm not sure how easy it would be to bypass for somebody with a reasonable amount of knowledge.

Best of luck with it.